# Filtering or removing from a list(Of T)

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

I have a method Which takes a list of objects.
Before persisting the object I have to remove some of them on some given condition

for eg(not the ideal!):

> A Company can have an Id and a list of Branches and a IsDeleted flag.
>   A Branch can have an Id and a list of Managers and a IsDeleted flag
>   A Manager can have an Id and a IsDeleted flag
>   Company -->Branches-->Managers

Whats the easy or the best way of filtering to ommit the combination of Id = 0 and IsDeleted = True  so I can iterate that and do specifics -- see the function below

- Thats if the company is marked as `Id = 0 and IsDeleted` then I want to ommit that altogether
- But If Only Branch Is marked as `Id=0 and Isdeleted` then the Company Should be there without a Branch
- If Only the Manager is matrked as `Id=0 and Isdeleted` then the Company and Branch should be there

> 

```
Private Function(comp as List(Of Company)) as Boolean
    'filter comp here and pass it to for loop??
    Dim filteredList as ...
    For each c as Company in filteredList 
    'do company specifis here
        For each b as Branch in c.Branches
        'do branch specific here
            For Each m as Manager in b.Managers
            'do manager specific here
            Next
        Next
    Save(c) ' saves child objects as well    
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this solve your problem?

```
Dim filtererdComp = comp _
    .Where(Function(c) c.Id<>0 Or Not c.IsDeleted)
    .ToList()
For each c as Company in filtererdComp
    c.Branches = c.Branches _
        .Where(Function(b) b.Id<>0 Or Not b.IsDeleted) _
        .ToList()
    For each b As Branch in c.Branches
        b.Managers = b.Managers _
            .Where(Function(m) m.Id<>0 Or Not m.IsDeleted) _
            .ToList()
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see you are filtering the company first which i understand.But filtererdComp  can still contain unwanted entries in Branches so I guess `c.Branches = c.Branches .Where(Function(b) b.Id<>0 Or Not b.IsDeleted).ToList()` resets Branches to the where condition?

Comment: First I create a list of filtered companies. Then I replace the list of branches in each filtered company by a filtered list of branches and finally I replace each list of managers in each filtered branch by a list of filtered managers. The result is a list of filtered managers containing filtered branches containing filtered managers.

Comment: Aren't you changing the original Company and Branch objects? I'm not sure this is desired.

Comment: Yes, this changes the original objects. It might be okey to get rid of them if they are marked as `IsDeleted` and have an ID of `0`. Tim Schmelter's solution keeps the original objects unchanged. It's up to the OP to decide.

Comment: @MarkJ I use Entity framework to save the changes. so removing from the original is what I required.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Linq:

```
Dim filtered = From c In comp Where Not c.IsDeleted OrElse c.Id <> 0
             From b In c.Branches Where Not b.IsDeleted OrElse b.Id <> 0
             From m In b.Managers Where Not m.IsDeleted OrElse m.Id <> 0
             Select New With {.Company = c, .Branch = b, .Manager = m}

For Each x In filtered
    Dim c As Company = x.Company
    Dim b As Branch = x.Branch
    Dim m As Manager = x.Manager
Next
```

or, if you want to enumerate each type separately:

```
Dim filteredComp = From c In comp Where Not c.IsDeleted OrElse c.Id <> 0
Dim filteredBranch = From c In filteredComp
                   From b In c.Branches Where Not b.IsDeleted OrElse b.Id <> 0
                   Select b
Dim filteredManager = From b In filteredBranch
                   From m In b.Managers Where Not m.IsDeleted OrElse m.Id <> 0
                   Select m

For Each c In filteredComp

Next
For Each b In filteredBranch

Next
For Each m In filteredManager

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Within each level of your iteration, loop through all the existing elements on that level. Use an if statement to check if the ID=0 and IsDeleted is true, in which case delete the entry.